# How to make group owner of /var/www/html/*

Tags: permissions

I am stuck at trying to change the owner of directory `/var/www/html/*` from user to group.

I want to make the group `developers` to be the owner of that directory and all sub-directories. Is it possible to make a group owner of directory instead of user in Ubuntu 14.04, and how ?

So far i tried `chown :developers -R /var/www/html/*` but it seems to be not working.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown -R apache2:developers /var/www/html`, assuming that apache2 is the appropriate user owner?

Answer (score 3):

First of all files will still have user owner.
They always have user and group owner.
Anyway - to make group owner set to developers for all contents of your dir:

```
groupadd developers
chgrp developers -R /var/www/html/*
```

This doesn't affect user owner.

Comment: So two different users can not edit same file in that directory ?

Comment: They can, as long as they have proper permissions on that file. Take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions  - it should clarify file permissions for you.

Comment: I think i do not understand it properly. For example how user `user1` and `user2` can have full access to all files and folders in `/var/www/html/*` ?

Comment: Please read the link I provided - it will clarify it. Long story short - one thing is who's the owner (user and group), another what are the permissions for user, group and others.

Comment: I have run `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/*` but when i try to edit file with `user2` with WinSCP it says the user has no permissions...